# Mouse and Keyboard not working in qemu emulator

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, qemu, gumstix

I am trying to run Yocto Image in qemu on my Ubuntu laptop with the following command.

```
qemu-system-arm -M overo -m 256 -sd ./test.img -clock unix -serial stdio -device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd
```

Qemu works fine and the image is booted pretty clean, but I am unable to use my keyboard and Mouse. On any key press I get this warning.

```
usb-kbd: warning: key event queue full
```

Any workaround for this unresponsive keyboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was, I need to specify USB bus number with device number for  USB Pass-Through. 
Get the list of USB's by this command `lsusb` and it will list them as following:

[image]

My keyboard bus number is 002 and address is 001. So, change the command based on the device number and address. So, my command will be as follows:

```
qemu-system-arm -M overo -m 256 -sd ./test.img -clock unix -serial stdio -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=2,hostaddr=1
```

You need to add this line `-usb -device usb-host,hostbus=2,hostaddr=1` based on the device number and address. To get cursor pointer working add `-show-cursor` as specified by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665412/mouse-and-keyboard-not-working-in-qemu-emulator/19673866#19673866)

Comment: how do you know is address=001, I see Bus 002 Device 003, no addresses... :(

Answer (score 4):

Add `-show-cursor` argument to your command.

i.e `qemu-system-arm -M overo -m 256 -sd ./test.img -clock unix -serial stdio -device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd -show-cursor`

That will emulate your cursor pointer

Comment: This works but I need to get my keyboard responsive. mouse pointer is emulating well but not keyboard. I am using console-image, so there's no use with mouse actually. Any idea how to get keyboard responsive?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, installing os x 10.0 and the keyboard stopped working, on installing os x 10.1 no mouse even, but after removing the following entries I got it to work (OS X gave me a hint saying USB error at start up in verbose mode)

```
-device usb-mouse -device usb-kbd
```

Comment: I found I had to put in those entries just to get past the "press these keys" bit on first boot.