# Qemu Sparc64 emulation - keyboard doesn't work (Windows, Ubuntu host tested)

Tags: cpu, emulation, qemu

people

I need to run sparc64 emulator in order to install Solaris 10 for sparc64. I tried to run it on following hosts:
Windows 10 Professional
Windows 10 Enterprise
Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
Ubuntu 21.04
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (ran on Windows hosted Hyper-v)

Every time I get this:

[image: qemu stdout]

Keyboard is not responsive and I can not continue.
You can also view that i8042 module used for the keyboard is not available.
Can someone help with how to enable keyboard (it is not usb keyboard, it is integrated - on notebook - used for all except for Win Server)?

The starting command for qemu is (minimalistic):

```
qemu-system-spark64 -cdrom sol-10-u11-ga-sparc-dvd.iso -drive file=Image.img -m 2G -boot d
```

Comment: Show the full command or definition for how you are starting this VM. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful here.

The guest likely doesn't understand the keyboard type that qemu is presenting. You may need to emulate a PS2 or other type of keyboard. The actual hardware keyboard type that is connected to your windows/ubuntu host system won't have a bearing on the keyboard that qemu presents to the guest.

Comment: @programmerq, thanks for the answer, and sorry for missing starting command.
I edited the initial question in way that added a command at the end.

Comment: Is anyone managed to run qemu on windows properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QEMU usb keyboard passthrough difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615794/qemu-usb-keyboard-passthrough-difficulties)

Comment: Thanx for the advice but no luck. I will try to build qemu v6.1.0 rc on my Win 10 (just need to set the env for that) and try again the same.